# jQuery animation stop

Tags: jquery, animation

So I got a html structure like

```
    <html>
      <body>
        <div class="window">
           ////some content
        </div>
      </body>
    <html>
```

and now want to create a window animation similiar to the one in windows 7 when minimizing/maximizing your window.
So far I got

```
    somejObject.on("click",function(){
        if(////some code checking whether window is to be minimized)         
            jObject.stop(true,false).animate({"width":"0px","height":"0px","top":vanishingPoint.top,"left":vanishingPoint.left,"margin-top":-activeprogOuterHeight/2,"margin-left":-activeprogOuterWidth/2,"opacity":"0.0"},windowAnimationDuration);
        else    ////maximize window
            jObject.stop(true,false).animate({"top":windowProperties.top,"left":windowProperties.left,"margin-top":windowProperties.margin_top,"margin-left":windowProperties.margin_left,"height":windowProperties.height,"width":windowProperties.width,"opacity":"1.0"},windowAnimationDuration);
    });
```

where `somejObject` is a div which causes on click the window-animation. `jObject` is a div with `class="window"` (see html markup), `vanishingPoint` holds the target coordinates, `activeprogOuterHeight` as well as `activeprogOuterWidth` the size of the target element of the animation,`windowProperties` holds the information necessary to place the window where it has been before minimizing and `windowAnimationDuration` is some value indicating the duration of the animation;

All in all nothing fancy, it is working and thus not really my question (just in case somebody wants to see some code).

As long as I click the object with a frequency one could expect from the average user, everything works just fine. However, when I start increasing the frequency over a certain level, the height of the div with `class="window"` starts shrinking slowly, and depending on how long I keep clicking, ending up in having no height left on the window container causing the inner html content to - well - not look like it should.

I played a little with the `stop()` arguments: First argument has to be `true` in order to prevent the queueing of the animation which is unwanted in my case. Whether I give both stops `true` as the second argument or a random combination of both, the problem remains.
What I get from the `stop()` documentation (http://api.jquery.com/stop/), the first argument being true should prevent the animations from queueing up whereas the second being `false` should just stop the animation leaving it in its current state causing the following animation to start off where the last one ended. Keeping that in mind I would expect something like the animation staying in a small range depending on the click frequency and then finishing on the last animation caused by the last click.

So what am I doing wrong?

**Edit 1**
Rough fiddle of what is going on: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/84G49/13/).

Comment: Hmm, I think the second argument to .stop should be true since it says "jumpToEnd". I'm going to tweak it myself. Could you please create a jsfiddle next time so it's easier to help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer based on your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a9fF4/ - first call `stop` and `animate` and only then update your `windowProperties`

Comment: Be sure to tidy the code if you want to use it, but it does the trick :-)

Comment: thanks a lot, it did the trick - although I'm somehow confused: I would make sense to me if the windowproperties would get updated in the callback, but since the animation is ansynchronous it shouldn't really matter if I put the windowproperties update code before or after the animate statement, should it?

Comment: When you first update the props and only then call ```stop``` the element's current position will be used - that's why you see it jumping around instead of it travelling to the place you want. If you first call ```stop``` jQuery (apparently) updates the element's position immediately and you never get a mid-way position.

Comment: In other words I *think* ```animate``` is async but ```stop``` has an immediate effect

Answer (score 0):

Calling `.stop(true, true)` should do the trick in general. See http://jsfiddle.net/8B8vw/ (When you remove the call to .stop from the fiddle, that's similar to your current situation, right?) So I would look for the problem somewhere else in the code (if stop does not work).